# VSCode Zoom in on .png

Tags: visual-studio-code, zooming

Is there a way to zoom in on an image in VSCode (.png in particular)? My repository contains some very small images, and I would like to view them without opening another application. I thought that the FontSize shortcuts plugin might be a workaround, but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of VS Code 1.36 it's very easy:

- To zoom in, just click on the picture. When the mouse is over it, the cursor becomes a magnifying glass with a small "+".
- To zoom out, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on it. While <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed, the cursor changes to a magnifying glass with a small "-".

Alternatively, the status bar in the lower-right corner displays some info about the picture, and one of the fields shows "100%": it's the current zoom level, just click on it and choose another one.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like my request worked and this feature was added!

Comment: @PrestonM Well, thank you for making the request in the first place! :-)

Comment: I want to move the zoomed-in picture with the mouse, but it does not work. A click also triggers zoom-in, so the drag with a mouse does, how to custom the action?

Comment: @W.Perrin I haven't used VS Code for a long time. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Note that on MacOS, you need to hold Option instead of Ctrl.

Answer (score 4):

On my mac OS Mojave, I need to use

`alt + click on the image` to zoom out.